# How can the Cross-correlation of two time series be used to measure similarity between vectors

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, signal-processing

Because cross correlation methods (like numpy.correlate) typically return vectors, how can they be used to determine the similarity of two input vectors

Comment: What do you mean when you say "similarity" between two vectors? Is this is a quantitative assessment or a qualitative?